# What's the easiest way to implement floating buttons UI view for OS X

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I want to implement an UI view like the emoji selection view for Slack

[image]

As far as I can tell, Slack's client is actually a web browser, so that would probably be something like

```
   <ul>
       <li style="float: left"><a href="#">:taco</a></li>
       ....
   </ul>
```

As if it's in `HTML`. However, I want to do it with Cocoa `UIview` for OS X, I wonder is there any standard UI views I can use to achieve the same purpose with minimum effort? How it should work is to flow the buttons to the next row if there is no more space at the right hand side.

I looked something like `NSTableView`, but there seems no floating for the item cell (maybe I need to implement it by myself?). I also checked `NSStackView`, when the width exceeds parent view, it's not flowing to the second row. Anyway, just like to know before I jump in too fast for a custom UI view.

Comment: You should use NSCollectionView for this purpose.

Comment: Just found something, looks like there is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer

Thanks to @Astoria, I think `NSCollectionView` is the right one to use, and the only problem is which layout to use. After googling around, I think

`NSCollectionViewFlowLayout` is the right one to use, it's a port from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (iOS), the document can be [found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html)

There is a talk at WWDC about it:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-225/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use `NSTokenField`-outlet as well. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/TokenFieldPurpose/TokenFieldPurpose.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555-CH3-SW4) to know more about this control. Each entry will be a `NSAttributedString` with attachment image at first position. Thus, there may be not necessary to include such a heavy solution as `NSCollectionView`-one.